# show overfitting with sklearn & random forest

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, computer-vision, random-forest

I followed this tutorial to create a simple image classification script:

https://blog.hyperiondev.com/index.php/2019/02/18/machine-learning/

```
train_data = scipy.io.loadmat('extra_32x32.mat')
# extract the images and labels from the dictionary object
X = train_data['X']
y = train_data['y']

X = X.reshape(X.shape[0]*X.shape[1]*X.shape[2],X.shape[3]).T
y = y.reshape(y.shape[0],)
X, y = shuffle(X, y, random_state=42)
....
clf = RandomForestClassifier()
print(clf)
start_time = time.time()
RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
               max_depth=None, max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
               min_impurity_split=1e-07, min_samples_leaf=1,
               min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
               n_estimators=10, n_jobs=1, oob_score=False, random_state=None,
               verbose=0, warm_start=False)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
preds = clf.predict(X_test)

print("Accuracy:", accuracy_score(y_test,preds))
```

It gave me an accuracy of approximately 0.7.

Is there someway to visualize or show where/when/if the model is overfitting? I believe this can be shown by training the model until we see that the accuracy of training is increasing and the validation data is decreasing. But how can I do so in the code?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can test overfitting and underfitting. If you want to look specifically at train and test scores and compare them you can do this with sklearns cross_validate[https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html#sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate]. If you read the documentation it will return you a dictionary with train scores (if supplied as train_score=True) and test scores in metrics that you supply.

sample code

model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000, random_state=1, criterion='entropy', bootstrap=True, oob_score=True, verbose=1)
cv_dict = cross_validate(model, X, y, return_train_score=True)

You can also simply create a hold out test set with train test split and compare your training and test scores using the test data set.

Comment: Here, X & y are the original X & y values, right? Not the train/test ones?

Comment: Although this would give us the training errors, my question is that how can we "show" that this is overfitting? And as mentioned in the qs, is there any way to "stop" training when it starts to overfit?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a library like Optuna, which will test various hyperparameters for you and you could use the methods mentioned above.